# Inform c or c++ compiler loop length is mutliple of 8

Tags: c++, c, gcc, clang

I want to write the following function in c++ (compiling using gcc 11.1 with `-O3 -mavx -std=c++17`)

```
void f( float * __restrict__ a, float * __restrict__ b, float * __restrict__ c, int64_t n) {
    for (int64_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) {
        a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
    }
}
```

This generates about 60 lines of assembly, many of which deal with the case where n is not a multiple of 8. https://godbolt.org/z/61MYPG7an

I know that `n` is always a multiple of 8. One way I could change this code is to replace `for (int64_t i = 0; i != n; ++i)` with `for (int64_t i = 0; i != (n / 8 * 8); ++i)`. This generates only about 20 assembly instructions. https://godbolt.org/z/vhvdKMfE9

However, on line 5 of the second godbolt link, there is an instruction to zero the lowest three bits of `n`. If there was a way to inform the compiler that `n` will always be a multiple of 8, then this instruction could be omitted with no change in behavior. Does anyone know of a way to do this on any c or c++ compiler (especially on gcc or clang)? In my case this doesn't actually matter, but I'm interested and not sure where to look.

Comment: You already have `#include <immintrin.h>`, why won't you use those intrinsics directly?

Comment: Hi Vlad,
that was left over from other experiments. I don't need it here. Sorry!

Comment: The answer below is cleaner, but I was saying that you can loop by 8 elements at a time, and process them at one using intrinsic AVX functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Declare the assumption with `__builtin_unreachable`

```
void f(float *__restrict__ a, float *__restrict__ b, float *__restrict__ c, int64_t n) {
    if(n % 8 != 0) __builtin_unreachable(); // control flow cannot reach this branch so the condition is not necessary and is optimized out
    for (int64_t i = 0; i != n; ++i) { // if control flow reaches this point n is a multiple of 8
        a[i] = b[i] + c[i];
    }
}
```

This produces [much shorter code](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,selection:(endColumn:37,endLineNumber:4,positionColumn:37,positionLineNumber:4,selectionStartColumn:37,selectionStartLineNumber:4,startColumn:37,startLineNumber:4),source:%27%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Avoid+f(float+*__restrict__+a,+float+*__restrict__+b,+float+*__restrict__+c,+int64_t+n)+%7B%0A++++if(n+%25+8+!!%3D+0)+__builtin_unreachable()%3B%0A++++for+(int64_t+i+%3D+0%3B+i+!!%3D+n%3B+%2B%2Bi)+%7B%0A++++++++a%5Bi%5D+%3D+b%5Bi%5D+%2B+c%5Bi%5D%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:40.54486815858167,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:g111,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-mavx+-std%3Dc%2B%2B17%27,selection:(endColumn:1,endLineNumber:1,positionColumn:1,positionLineNumber:1,selectionStartColumn:1,selectionStartLineNumber:1,startColumn:1,startLineNumber:1),source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+gcc+11.1+(C%2B%2B,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:56.884457937207586,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:1,editor:1,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,wrap:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27Output+of+x86-64+gcc+11.1+(Compiler+%231)%27,t:%270%27)),k:2.256702161667603,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4).

Comment: I suspect you could achieve something similar in MSVC using `__assume(...)`. Either `if (n % 8 != 0 ) __assume(0);`, or `__assume(n % 8 == 0)`